# Google App Engine 301 redirect in PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, redirect, http-status-code-301, app.yaml

For example, you have
example.com (naked domain, Type A)
www.example.com (ghs.googlehosted.com, type CNAME)
and you want to 301 redirect www.example.com to example.com. the follow is redirect.php

```
> <?
> $direct_redirects = array("www.example.com" => "http://example.com",);
> 
> $path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
> $redirect_url = $direct_redirects[$path];
if(!is_null($redirect_url)) {
>     header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
>     header("Location: $redirect_url"); }
```

app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: redirect.php

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

it doesn't work.

How coudd you do 301 redirect at GAE with php?

Comment: use exit after `header("Location: $redirect_url");`

Comment: @Irfan It's still same. Totally I was wrong. It is for just 'path' redirect, not 'host url'. Thanks. I solved the problem.

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm facing the similar issue. But my app is in Node. Do I need to write in yaml only or my server routing as well? If you could help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with redirection of URL.
Let's say you have bought example.com and you have connected it with google cloud but you want to do 301 redirects to www.example.com...So for that
Go to your account page from where you have bought example.com (godaddy/namecheap or any other)
Then there in "DNS setting" page add(or edit already added) record for "URL redirect" and there add the desired target URL to "www.example.com" with addition field having options "masked","unmasked" & "301(Moved Permanently)", choose the 301(Moved Permanently) option and after few minutes 301 redirect will work.